# z-index problem in ie6

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index, internet-explorer-6

I have a complex page. tag `b` is some line on the photo. tag `span` is jquery animate opacity for the photo. I have set z-index:0 for the top parent of all the divs, but it still not work. where is the problem?

```
<div class="wrap" style="z-index:0">
  <div class="content" style="z-index:1">
    <div class="col1">
      <div class="galley">
        <b class="line" style="z-index:2"></b>
          <div class="photo">
            <div class="picture" style="z-index:3">
              <a herf="">
                <span style="z-index:3"></span>
                <img src="img1.jpg">
              </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index property only works for elements that are siblings in the tree; it doesn't position children relative to their ancestors.  Child elements are generally above their parents in the z-order.  You must have some other crazy CSS stuff going on as well.

Can you create a page that minimally reproduces the problem and provide a link, along with the behavior you expect to see?

Comment: Ok, I will try to minimally elememts in my page, and try to solve this problem.